# android textview size huge

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView in a FrameLayout with a background that is 150 x 53 pixels, but when my app loads, the background takes up the whole width of the view, I only desire it to take up the width of the text.  How might I do this?

```
<TextView  
            android:id="@+id/txtPrice"       
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dip"               
            android:layout_marginTop="164dip"    
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"   
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"  
            android:gravity="center"                                     
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="46dip"                   
            android:textColor="#ffffff"                     
            android:background="@drawable/greenbg"   
            android:text="$0.00" />
```

Comment: answering my own question, i needed to convert my image to a 9-patch image

Answer (score 2):

I think this is happening because of this "android:background="@drawable/greenbg", isn't it?
try to remove it test the app.
if this drawable has a big width, the textView will became big too.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<TextView  
            android:id="@+id/txtPrice"       
            android:layout_width="150dp"         
            android:layout_height="53dp"         
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dip"               
            android:layout_marginTop="164dip"    
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"   
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"  
            android:gravity="center"                                     
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="46dip"                   
            android:textColor="#ffffff"                     
            android:background="@drawable/greenbg"   
            android:text="$0.00" />
```

you have to give the layout_height and layout_width fix according to framelayout size.